# Java list set method

Tags: java

Okay, I have had a question, my code has seemed to work, but I have not tested it particuarly well.

I'm trying to set an element in an ArrayList.

```
ArrayList<StringBuilder> g=new ArrayList<StringBuilder>();
//set the array contents
g.get(2).append("Something");
```

I know that doing something like

```
StringBuilder q=g.get(2);
q.append("something else?");
g.set(2,q);
```

works, and is probably the right way to do it, but it seems like such long way of doing it.

Am I doing this right, if I'm not, then is the second way I've mentioned the only way?

Comment: You don't need to set the same StringBuilder back to the list as it won't do anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a list of `StringBuilder`, which are modified in place, then the first method is fine. If you have a list of some immutable type (like `String`), then since you cannot change the object that you get out, you have to use a variant of the second method, because the result is not the same object.

e.g.

```
List<StringBuilder> widgets = new ArrayList<StringBuilder>();
// ...
StringBuilder widget = widgets.get(0);
widget.append(" version 2");
```

vs

```
List<String> widgets = new ArrayList<String>();
// ...
String widget = widgets.get(0);
widgets.set(2, widget + " version 2");
```

Comment: Thanks, though I wasn't actually asking about StringBuilders in general, more the overall practice of modifying items in lists of mutable items.

Comment: @jaked122 You should tell this in your question then.

Comment: Why, the stringbuilder class has no special treatment in java, so thus any advice given on this would work on most, if not all classes.

Comment: If you mutate an item in the list, then you don't need to store it again. If you take an item and compute some new object (e.g. because the original was immutable), then you need to call `set`.

`StringBuilder` and `String` were simply examples of mutable and immutable objects (inspired by your question).

Answer (score 1):

When calling List#get() method you are retrieving a reference to your StringBuilder object. StringBuilder is a mutable object. So if you want to modify your StringBuilder's contents at index 2 then you don't need to set a reference again after you modify it. Hence the following is enough:

```
g.get(2).append("Something");
```

Answer (score 0):

`g.get(2).append("Something");` works if you initialized the list values with `StringBuilder` instances. Otherwise you will get a `NullPointerException`.

Note that in your code you define an `ArrayList` of type `StringBuilder` but then you try to assign an `ArrayList` of type `Integer` to it, which does not work

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking of a mutable type that would work, Integer didn't work, so I partially changed the code to StringBuilder.

Comment: Both methods will only work if the list is initialized; they behave the same with the difference that the second one does and unnecessary set.